# How to trigger Liquibase from eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, liquibase, jhipster

I have Eclipse (Spring Tool Suite, latest version) with the liquibase plugin installed.

What I want to do is generate a first change log from my existing database, which is this code form the command line, I understand.

```
liquibase --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver \
      --classpath=\path\to\classes:jdbcdriver.jar \
      --changeLogFile=com/example/db.changelog.xml \
      --url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" \
      --username=scott \
      --password=tiger \
      generateChangeLog
```

But I cant see any sign of Liquibase functions in Eclipse.

How do you run Liquibase from within Eclipse? I am hope it will be easier, not having to find driver paths, etc

I am doing this as I want to try Jhipster, and it need a Liquibase change log (cant find an example of someone do that either, in case you know of one!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in liquibase functions in eclipse. If you are trying to run a Liquibase often from within Eclipse the best option is to use the [Ant](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/ant/index.html) or [Maven](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/index.html) interface since they can be easily called from Eclipse commands.

GenerateChangeLog is something you generally only need to run once to bootstrap an existing database into being managed by liquibase, so a quick command line call may be the easiest for you.

The [Liquibase Quick Start Guide](http://www.liquibase.org/quickstart.html) has an example changelog file for reference as well.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I will stick to native usage. 

I have installed a Liquibase plugin  Liquibase Eclipse Feature 1.2.1.201309060942 com.svcdelivery.liquibase.eclipse.feature.feature.group SVC Delivery
with a copywrite to Nick Wilson, but I cant find any documentation, so I am to afraid to hit "Project right click->Configure->Convert to Liquibase project"

Comment: @Nathan Voxland hot to do in order to use liquibase in eclipse without any own project? i downloaded liquibase 5.3.5 and liquibase-core, i imported liquibase as existing maven project but i can't execute it... sorry for stupid question

Comment: You should just be able to run "mvn liquibase:update" once you have set up as described in http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/

Answer (score 0):

You can install Liquibase Plugin from Windows Menu > Market place.
further information: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/liquibase-eclipse-plugin

Comment: It's seems, The current version of this plugin is incompatible with Eclipse 2020 and later so that you can not install it on these versions of Eclipse unless in future its developer releases a new version.